# Import error using Python uadt package (machine learning)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, python-import, importerror

I'm tyring to use this program (https://github.com/tbabej/uadt) to test my pcap captures and do some machine learning. I use the command git clone to have everything on my pc, then I use "pip -r install requirements.txt" and then I execute "setup.py install".
Then I need to generate my dataset, so I go to /uadt/uadt/analysis/ and run dataset.py as stated in the Readme, but I get the error

```
from uadt import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'uadt'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to install it?
I just need the files in the analysis folder because I've already done the other steps on my own.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uadt-dataset", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('uadt==0.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'uadt-dataset')())
  File "/usr/local/bin/uadt-dataset", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/uadt-0.8.0-py3.9.egg/uadt/analysis/dataset.py", line 26, in <module>
    from uadt.analysis.flow import Flow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/uadt-0.8.0-py3.9.egg/uadt/analysis/flow.py", line 13, in <module>
    from uadt import config
ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'uadt' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/uadt-0.8.0-py3.9.egg/uadt/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Looks like that project's readme is way out of date; it doesn't even expose the scripts that it mentions or has renamed them, or actually expose any module or object called `uadt.config`. Try opening a GitHub issue with the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `config.py.in` file into the `uadt` folder.
This could fix your import issue.